# React pass child class method to parent functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get `adaptValue` from `Component1` and use it in `Component2`. For some reason this does not work since my `adaptValue` is always null/undefined. Is it because `Parent` is a functional component?

```
const Parent = (props) => {
    const [adaptValue, setAdapt] = useState(null);
    return (
        <div>
            <Component1 setAdapt={setAdapt}/>
            <Component2 adaptValue={adaptValue}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default class Component1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
  
    adaptValue = (value) =>{
        DO_SOMETHING_WITH_VALUE
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setAdapt(this.adaptValue);
    }

    render() {
        return something;
    }
}

export default class Component2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
  
    someFunction = (value) =>{
        ...
        //adaptValue is always undefined
        this.props.adaptValue(value)
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Made the parent a class component in the end and all works. Wondering whether this is a compatibility issue between functional or class-based components.

Comment: Please MCVE. `Component2` uses `setAdapt` (which is `undefined`) and in `Component1` there is that `DO_SOMETHING_WITH_VALUE` which could be...anything. (this assuming that it's correct and you want to have a function there to change the old value instead of the value itself).

Comment: Apologies, removed componentDidMount() from Component2 - copy paste issue. `DO_SOMETHING_WITH_VALUE` can be anything.

Comment: Does your adaptValue function in Component1 even return something ? If adaptValue is set at null at the beginning and you're not setting anything it will be ... null

Comment: `adaptValue` is a void function. It just changes some class variables in Component1. I want to be able to call `Component1` method `adaptValue` from `Component2`.

Comment: Do you receive an error? I can imagine that calling `this.props.adaptValue(value)` will throw "null is not a function" when `Component1` is not yet mounted. Shouldn't you pass a NOP function as default instead of `null`? something like: `const [adaptValue, setAdapt] = useState(() => {})`

Answer (score 1):

When passing `setAdapt` to `Component1` ... `setAdapt` is already a function. There is no need to wrap it in another one. `Component1` will modify the value, and `Component2` will display it. Function Components have nothing to do with the behavior.

Try ...

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Component1 from "./Component1";
import Component2 from "./Component2";

export default function App() {
  const [adaptValue, setAdapt] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 setAdapt={setAdapt} />
      <Component2 adaptValue={adaptValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Component1.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Component1 extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.setAdapt("New Value");
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Set Value</button>;
  }
}
```

Component2.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Component2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return !!this.props.adaptValue ? (
      <h1>{`"${this.props.adaptValue}" <- Value of adaptValue`}</h1>
    ) : (
      <h1>adaptValue Not Assigned</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

[Sandbox Example ...](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-violet-oq21s?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi Jason. I want to use `adaptValue` **method** from `Component1` in `Component2`. If `Parent` would be a class component, then it would work. This issue came after someone refactored the `Parent` in a functional component. Thanks.

Comment: Component1.js - gives value not assigned, whereas it should be assigned to a method.

It should write:
`
ƒ () {
      console.log('this is just a statement in a class method');
    }
`
`
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Component1 extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.setAdapt(this.doSomething);
  };

  doSomething = () => {
    console.log('this is just a statement in a class method')
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Set Value</button>;
  }
}
`

Comment: So what you are saying is that `adaptValue` itself is an instance function that is defined within `Component1`. .. Interesting, frankly, if it were me, I would make them all function components. It makes for much cleaner code.

Comment: Exactly! I ended up making the parent a class and all works now...Was keen to see whether there is a compatibility issue between functional or class based components.

Comment: @stoicky Both a class and a functional component should work. The issue might be that you don't converted it correctly into a functional component. If you provide your code for both versions we might be able to point out why one version does work and the other one doesn't. This might be better suited as a new question, since you would have to completely overhaul this question. Something like "Passing a callback fails when trying to convert a class component to a functional one" Then explain your situation and add the two samples.